# PHP: calling on an instance's private method inside an instance's static class

Tags: php, private

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
class A {

  public function __construct($a) {
    // stuff here
  }

  public static function request() {
    $instance = new self("hi");
    $instance->bye(); // this weirdly only sometimes throws errors
  }

  private function bye() {
    // stuff here
  }

}

A::request();
```

The line of interest is `$instance->bye()` - is this allowed within the static context in a way but when called on an instance and inside the same class as the constructor? Or is this not a good practice in general? It's strange that this only throws errors sometimes of calling on a private method with no context.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-other-objects

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @wogsland posted a comment - apparently it was due to PHPStorm debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is fine and PHPStorm debugger was creating the issue and screwing up the context hence why the error only happened sometimes which apparently happens on our systems ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Calling a regular method from a static method should never be done.

As there may be no instance at all (Ex: Calling `A::request()` directly), it will throw an error.
A static method will be the same for all instances of the class, so it won't be able to access non-static properties.

What could but shouldn't be done is calling an object **of the same type** private method from a static method:

```
<?php
class A {
    private function foo()
    {
        print("bar");
    }

    static public function bar($a)
    {
        $a->foo();
    }
}

$a = new A();

A::bar($a);
?>
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: I don't this is a general rule (your example). The classes should be of the same type.

Comment: You're right, added this clarification in the answer